# R machine learning model deployment as webservice

Tags: r, web-services, machine-learning

Is there any way to deploy machine Learning model written in R language as a webservice, I know we have Flask in python and many more too, but didnt come across for any such library for R Machine learning code.

Comment: Have you taken a look at Shiny?

Comment: May be ruby will help you.

Comment: You can use the `shiny` package to create webapps from arbitrary R code. If you want to host online you could either use a service like [shinyapps.io](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shinyapps/) or you could host your own internal shiny server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others suggested, you can use `R-Shiny` to build an app which you can later deploy as a web service easily. Moreover, you can use html code inside shiny so you can customise your layout to your heart's content. If you are using RStudio (which I definitely encourage if you don't), you only need to select File > New File > Shiny Web App... Have a look at documentation and examples [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/).

However, if you only want to create a compact and fast web service without having to build a layout etc, I would suggest you use R [plumber](https://github.com/trestletech/plumber) library. This is a good solution if you don't need anything too fancy and also is easily implementable by adding decorators to your current code.

Hope this helps!